# Tabulator colspan or default message for blank table?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm currently setting up a tabulator table, however it will be initially blank until selecting from a choice of filters.

My initial plan was to create a colspan across the table with a unique field name which I could filter to (simply saying "Please select an option", or something to that effect), however a colspan seems extremely complicated to implement within tabular.

Any help on doing this or any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I should say, the table is filled with data at the start, so the placeholder does not appear!

EDIT: Nevermind, an easy solution. Simply filter on something that doesn't exist in the table, and the placeholder will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, an easy solution. Simply filter on something that doesn't exist in the table, and the placeholder will appear.